# PHP error finder

Tags: php

I am fixing a site of php errors down to notice. They way I am doing this is by enabling error_reporting and walking through the site, spotting errors and fixing them. I have noticed however, that this way I'm missing errors that are in unseen parts of a page, ie hidden inputs, invisible divs etc. Searching the source doesn't feel very convenient nor reliable.

I thought of creating an error handler either mailing me the errors or throwing an exception. The former would create a mess, the latter will only allow to spot one error and sometimes still will require viewing the source.

The point here is there's thousands of these errors, so even saving a couple of second on each would add up to a substantial time saving.

The question is if there's software that would highlight these errors for me, for instance a FF/Chrome extension?

Comment: Why not just look in the error log? If you use apache it should be located in apaches log folder.

Comment: Enable `error_reporting`, but disable `display_errors` and watch the server logs.

Comment: error log it bit hard to see which have been fixed and which not + the site is under cpanel and errors are being written to different locations depending on the requested file.

Comment: After you fix the errors you see, delete the `error_log` or remove those lines that you have fixed, and save.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, setting up a custom error handler and piping error to FirePHP seems to do the trick. This shows me error from referenced files as well.

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $br = php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? '' : '<br>';

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_NOTICE:  $errorType = 'Notice';  break;
        case E_WARNING: $errorType = 'Warning'; break;
        default:        $errorType = 'Error';   break;
    }

    $message = "$errorType: $errstr $br\n in $errfile $br\n on line $errline";
    if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
        throw new Exception($message);
    } else {
        \FirePHP::getInstance(true)->error($message);
    }
});
```